# Referrer URL logic Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ref

We have a referrer URL logic in Wordpress which looks like `https://example.com/?ref=userid`. We are trying to switch this to something like `https://example.com/ref/userid`. The code we use right now is:

```
// Ref Button
function func_register_button( $atts ) {

    if(isset($_GET['ref']) && is_valid_username($_GET['ref'])){
        $enter_link = 'https://example.com/sponsor/' . $_GET['ref'];
    }else{
        $enter_link = 'https://example.com/sign-up';
    }


    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'text' => __('Yes, I want to join now')
    ), $atts );

    $btn = '<a class="cta-btn" href="' . $enter_link . '" target="_blank">' . $a['text'] . '</a>';

    return $btn;

}
add_shortcode( 'register_button', 'func_register_button' );
```

I am looking forward to hear your ideas and suggestions. Hope you can push us into the right direction :-)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use parse_url() http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php to get the path, then replace $_GET['ref'] with that parsed value. Try it first.

Comment: Thanks! With parse url the problem is that visitors get redericted to 404 Page because of the permalink structure of Wordpress.

Comment: You should also override the url routing somewhere, but I'm not that familiar with Wordpress.